# Plot lat, long from multiple csv files on a single map with legends on side with different colors using plotly

Tags: python, csv

I am using plotly. Get the data from 1st csv in df1. Get the data in df2 from another csv. According to this there will be 2 fig1 = px.scatter_mapbox and fig2 = px.scatter_mapbox. How to merge these 2 so that I can plot the points on map with different colors from different csv.